# for some reason, python not responding when i quit it(mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

for some reason, python did not respond when I quit it
[screenshot of python didn't respond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXvBN.png)

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
size=(320, 320)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("space invader")
icons=pygame.image.load('info.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icons)
running=True
def player():
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
```

do you have any idea what the freak is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly the question is trying to achieve other than to run to its end. The code was missing necessary indentation, this works:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
size=(320, 320)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("space invader")
icons=pygame.image.load('info.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icons)
running=True
def player():
     while running:
          for event in pygame.event.get():
               if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running=False
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    pygame.quit()
```

I would still point out that the function `player()` needs to be called somewhere presumably...